# Use of put with >> in the state monad

Tags: haskell, state-monad

From *Thinking Functionally with Haskell* (pg 248):

> You can think of type `State s a` as being
>
> ```
> type State s a = s -> (a,s)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> put :: s -> State s ()
> get :: State s s
> state :: (s -> (a,s)) -> State s a
> ```
>
> ... `state` can be defined using `put` and `get`:
>
> ```
> state f = do {s <- get; let (a,s') = f s;
>               put s'; return a}
> ```

Which I believe can be rewritten this way:

```
get >>= \s ->
    let (a,s') = fs in
        put s' >> return a
```

So what is the purpose of `put s'`, if `>>` throws away its return value?

Comment: An analogous question that might (or might not!) be enlightening: what is the purpose of `putStrLn "hello world!"` in `main = putStrLn "hello world!" >> main`, if `>>` throws away its return value?

Comment: I see now that the phrase "if >> throws away its return value?" distracts from the intent of my question, which wasn't to ask "what's the point of this operator (in general)" but rather, "how does it function in the context of the state monad?" @jcast's response was what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>>` doesn't throw away everything from the first argument.  The definition for the state monad (ignoring the `newtype`)

```
a >> b = \s -> let (x, s') = a s in b s'
```

So the state form the first argument is used by `>>`, but the 'return value' (the `x` component of the result) is ignored.  That's the point of the state monad --- to track changes to the state without the programmer having to explicitly take them into account.

Apparently, this isn't explained properly by what the OP has been reading, so here's how you can derive the definition above.  The definition of `>>` across all monads is

```
a >> b = a >>= \ _ -> b
```

The definition of `>>=` for the state monad (ignoring `newtype`s) is

```
a >>= f = \ s -> let (x, s') = a s in f x s'
```

Now, substituting the definition of `>>=` into the definition of `>>` above and simplifying, we get:

```
a >> b = let f = \ _ -> b in \ s -> let (x, s') = a s in f x s'
    = \ s -> let (x, s') = a s in (\ _ -> b) x s'
    = \ s -> let (x, s') = a s in b s'
```

Comment: Where (other than source code) would I have found this definition? The docs I've seen frequently don't include >>

Comment: @planarian Source code is generally where you find definitions. It is the exception rather than the rule to see them elsewhere.

Comment: That surprises me. I'd always thought Hoogle was the place to look for them.

Comment: @planarian Hoogle will get you a type declaration and a link to the docs; often there is a link to the source from there. In the specific case of `(>>)` (and other class methods), of course, you want the source for the instance, not the source for the declaration of `(>>)`.

Comment: Ah, "docs" = "Haddock".  Yeah, I wouldn't rely on those. I would recommend finding some long-form tutorials that at least have some thought put into them. (I don't have a good recommendation right now, sorry).

Answer (score 3):

> So what is the purpose of `put s'`, if `>>` throws away its return value?

`(>>)` does throw away the return value, but we don't use `put` for the return value. The type of `put` is:

```
put :: s -> State s ()
```

The return value is of `put` is a `()`, and `()` is for the most part just an uninteresting placeholder. The meaningful part of what `put` does -- replacing the state -- is not reflected in the return value. A similar case is the type of `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`.

Answer (score 3):

`State` is an example where the monad abstraction is used to encapsulate an *effect*. In such cases, it's perfectly normal to have operations in which the effect of the operation is important, but it might not have a meaningful return value.

I'll illustrate with an example. Consider everyone's favorite recursive algorithm, the Fibonacci sequence:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 1 = 0
fib 2 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

We all know this is a pretty inefficient way to calculate these numbers, but *how* inefficient is it? If we were using a lesser language, we would probably be tempted to hack in a mutable variable and increment it every time `fib` is called. We can do something similar in Haskell in a purely functional way using `State`.

Let's define a new version of fib:

```
fib' :: Int -> State Int Int
fib' 1 = modify (+1) >> return 0
fib' 2 = modify (+1) >> return 1
fib' n = modify (+1) >> (+) <$> fib' (n-1) <*> fib' (n-2)
```

Now we can simultaneously compute the nth number and also count how many calls were made:

```
> runState (fib' 7) 0
(8,25)
> runState (fib' 10) 0
(34,109)
> runState (fib' 30) 0  -- this takes about 5 seconds on my machine
(514229,1664079)
```

Ok, that's great but how does it answer the question? The point to note in the above implementation is `modify (+1)`. This has the effect of adding 1 to the counter, but doesn't have any useful result on its own. We use `>>` to sequence it with the next operation, which does have a useful result, namely the computation.